# How to make iOS 13 map display both the user location and another annotation even when they are close together

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview

By default, in ios12 map, both the user location and another added annotation are displayed together even when their locations are very close.  But in ios13 map, the user location will hide another location if they are close together.

If somebody knows how to display the user location and another location together at close proximity in iOS13, please help.

Below is an image generated on a iOS12 phone. On iOS13, everything is the same except that the custom user location image is not displayed.

[image: ios 12 map image]

Comment: can you post screen shot of ios12 and ios 13 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the user location and the added annotation will be displayed (even when they are closely located) if they are both assigned a value of MKFeatureDisplayPriorityRequired.